# Can Salt used to kasher meat have additives [such as anti-caking agents]?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

Can Salt being used to kasher meat have additives [such as anti-caking agents]? I see that some "kosher salt" companies have this added (e.g. Morton), can they still be used to Kasher meat or chicken?

Comment: The main criterion of kashering salt is that it should stick to the surface of the meat and also enable the blood to flow out easily. For example that is what the salt must be neither too fine or too coarse. I would find it odd that anti-caking agent would be added to kashering salt, which has relatively large grains, as these do not tend to cake anyway. If the salt is so fine that it is caking without an anti-caking agent, it is probably too fine for kashering salt anyway.

Comment: anti caking agents usually means something like cellulose or starch. to imagine that koshering salt in the days of yore was completely free of impurities like that is really a stretch.

Comment: @DoubleAA - The specific agent in Morton salt is "Yellow prussiate of soda", I"m  not sure what effect it can have on drawing out blood.

Comment: @פריזהב Probably not much given how little of it there is in there. But anyway how would you measure it? You can't say the salt must be 100% sodium chloride since chazal didn't have that, and you can't start quantifying how much blood is removed with different additives since salting meat for halacha isn't a scientific process whereby X blood molecules must come out or whatever. Seemingly if it looks like salt and tastes like salt, it's halachically salt. I don't know what other answer is structurally possible. I have no source for this though

Comment: @DoubleAA - I see your point. Thank You